# Given a finite linear group of order $n$, why the sum of their matrices add up to $nI$?

Tags: representation-theory

I'm reading Steinberg's *Representation theory of finite groups.* In the second and third exercise here:

> [image]

I have made some experiments like thinking about the representation

$$\Bbb{Z}/3\Bbb{Z}\to \{\begin{bmatrix}
1 &0 \\ 
 0&1 
\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}
 1&1 \\ 
 0&1 
\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}
 1&-1 \\ 
 0&1 
\end{bmatrix}  \} $$

And noticed that they indeed add up to $\begin{bmatrix}
 3&0 \\ 
 0& 3
\end{bmatrix}$

But I can't explain why. Can you give me a hint? It is perhaps something very silly I may be missing.

Comment: There is nothing in this theorem that suggests that the sum of the matrices will in general be $nI$. Notice that part 3. **only** holds for $v \in V^{G}$.

Comment: @MorganRodgers I thought the following: $\sum \varphi_g v=\varphi_{g_1}v+\dots + \varphi_{g_n}v=(\varphi_{g_1}+\dots + \varphi_{g_n})v$ and hence $(\varphi_{g_1}+\dots + \varphi_{g_n})$ must be $nI$ (so that we can cancel out with $\frac{1}{|G|}$). This led me to think that perhaps that would be true because I couldn't think about what would make it true for $v\in V^{G}$ but not for other vectors.

Comment: In fact it is the other way: there is nothing to force it to be true for other vectors just because it is true for the vectors in $V^{G}$. The answer of metamorphy gives some good examples where this fails to happen since $V^{G}$ is trivial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put a $G$-invariant inner product on $V$ using Weyl's unitary trick. That is, pick any inner product, then "symmetrize" it, i.e. average it over its $G$-orbit, so $\langle u,v\rangle_G=\sum_{g\in G}\langle \rho(g)u,\rho(g)v\rangle$.

Let $W$ be the orthogonal complement of $V^G$. So $V=V^G\oplus W$ is a direct sum of representations. Write $\Sigma$ for the sum $\sum_{g\in G}\rho(g)$ of linear transformations $\rho(g)$ corresponding to group elements $g$.

Because this is a direct sum of representations, every $\rho(g)$ must be block-diagonal. On $V^G$ each $\rho(g)$ acts trivially, so $\sum$ must act as $nI$ where $n=|G|$. However if $w\in W$, then $\Sigma w$ is a fixed point, so it must be within $V^G$, a contradiction unless $\Sigma w=0$. Therefore, it has the block-diagonal form

$$ \Sigma = \begin{bmatrix} nI & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}. $$

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't hold in general. For example, consider the cyclic group of order $n$, with a trivial 1D representation over $\mathbb{C}$ (by $n$-th roots of unity), or, if you prefer, with a 2D representation over $\mathbb{R}$ (by rotation matrices). [In both cases we have $V^G=\{0\}$.]

Comment: See my comment below the question.